# Maven to generate cross-platform installer for a Command Line (CLI) app

Tags: java, maven

I've tried (almost) all solutions, starting with

- Using Launch4j - works for Windows, does not create installer, more so cross platform installer
- Using JavaFX - create installer, but CLI app does not work since JavaFX is a UI framework and command line does not print on console

What could be the solution of a Java CLI app to be packaged as native installer for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux that will package along with it a JRE?

Comment: The [oracle-documentation for the javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) itself contains that limitation ("Package per target platform"), so why not just creating a jar-bundle as a ZIP-file? It is because of the "bundled" JRE, which is required ... so my question to this: do you NEED to ship the JRE with your app?